# View Controller loads before data is pulled from firebase login

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have the code below and I'm trying to store latitude coordinates and longitude coordinates into 2 arrays. My problem is the controller loads before I even have the chance to retrieve the data from firebase. currently I'm using a callback but fail to store the data in the array.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,        CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()
var latArray = [Double]()
func getWorkersList(callback: @escaping ((_ data:[Restaurant]) ->Void )) {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("AthensRestaurants/Restaurants").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var results = [Restaurant]()

        for res in snapshot.children{
            let res = Restaurant(snapshot: res as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            results.append(res)
        }

        self.restaurantArray = results.sorted(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in
            u1.name < u2.name
        })
        callback(results)

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
var dataBaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    helpMe()
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    getWorkersList(callback: { (data:[Restaurant]) -> Void in
        print(data)
        for item in data {
            self.latArray.append(item.latitude)
        }
        print(self.latArray.count)
        print("hello")
    })
}
func helpMe(){
print("hello")
    print(latArray.count)
}
```

}

Comment: when you say you "fail to store the data in the array", is nothing being added to `restaurantArray`?  Or are entries being added and you simply need to populate your view with the array results?

Comment: well if you look at function helpmeet() when its called it returns 0.

Comment: right before the `callback(results)`, try doing this:  `print("self.restaurantArray count is \(self.restaurantArray.count)")` and tell me how many results you get.

Comment: the output is 7

Comment: try changing `print(self.latArray.count)` to `print("latArray count is \(self.latArray.count)"` and let me know if you see something other than zero.

Comment: the output is 0

Comment: This is the wrong way to use Firebase; it should not be used like a function call because Firebase is asynchronous and should be coded that way. Change your logic to call the Firebase observe function, which retrieves the data, and then populate the arrays *within the observe closure* and then open/display the view. Optionally, you can display the view then call the Firebase observe function but only work with the array's *within the closure* after the data is returned from Firebase. Get rid of the callbacks etc as they just aren't needed if the rest of the code is correct.